# Redirecting AWK output as input to GDB

Tags: gdb, awk, redirect

I am doing a

```
ps | grep process_name | awk '{if ($2 == "process_name")  {print $1} }'
```

which displays the process_id for the process name

After that I do a `gdb -p process_id`. I want to combine these two statements into a single statement. Any suggestions ?

```
ps | grep process_name | awk '{if ($2 == "process_name")  {print $1} }'
```

Output : process_id

```
gdb -p process_id
```

Comment: Your awk command can be simplified to awk '$2=="process_name" {print $1}'

Answer (score 0):

No need for grep or awk or any other external commands. This is what `pgrep` is made for:

```
PID=$(pgrep process_name) && gdb -p $PID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the bash shell, you can actually use variable substitution:

```
gdb -p $(pgrep process_name)
```